# using phonegap to convert website to an app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

So My website is already built and fully functional on I built it using ajax, jquery,html, and php , so I am trying to figure when converting over to phonegap am I creating all new php files to attach to phonegap server or am I just calling/wrapping my website using the files I already have from my website  ,  I guess what im trying to ask is when I edit my website files using FTP  should my app be automatically updated because im using ajax to call php files on my website server or do i need to create the files separate it should have 0 affect on my app unless I edit that as well ,

The reason why im asking because all of my website php files checking to see if  cookies and sessions are set else redirect to index.php and dont really understand how thats going to work using the phonegap app, completely new to this , hope im being very clear on what im asking

Comment: Cordova isn't a server. You can't use PHP with Cordova.

Comment: i know im using ajax to make calls to my website  php ajax url: https://www.example.com/php/runquery.php

Comment: Then I don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: would it be better to duplicate my  files from my website and store them on phonegap server , or should i make a call to my website index.php and load it in my index.html phone gap server using ajax

Comment: If you are fetching your website every time your app is launched, then it's not really an app. You just made a web browser without an address bar. An app is an independent piece of software that should not depend on any server, except when making requests to web services.

Comment: thanks man that answered my quesitonn bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Load your website to the app using Jquery load() or by Ajax or by InApp browser.

If you want to show your website to a div, you can do it by load() or by ajax call

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Load"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="ajax"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
/*Using Jquery Load()*/
$('#Load').load('http://www.google.co.in');

/*Using ajax*/
$.ajax({
  dataType:'html',
  url:'http://www.google.co.in',
  success:function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html($(data).children());   
  }
});
```

OR by [Inapp browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

```
window.open('http://www.google.co.in','_self');
```

Before using inappbrowser you must install the plugin to your project To add inappbrowser to project by commanline

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

Comment: do you think its good to load my website like that as the other guy commented saying that pretty much if I did that my project wouldnt be an app but more just a website without a url  , or should  remake the website on phonegap server?

Comment: So only phonegap have inappbrowser plugin to load external website pages. Try to use that